# Pass an array to javascript function on anchor tag onclick

Tags: javascript

I am using an anchor tag for showing dynamic links.I am using javascript function to be called

on anchor onclick.This is working fine.But the issue is that i want to send an array of values to that javascript function.How can i do that?
My anchor tag is defined below,

```
 <a onclick="getbatchreport();" id="anch<?php echo "B-" . trim($value['BATCH_NO']); ?>"><?php echo "B-" . trim($value['BATCH_NO']); ?></a>
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with php, it's a javascript question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php //stuff and things ?>

<a href='#' onClick='functionName(<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>)'>Click Me</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   function functionName(arr){

       arr = JSON.parse(arr);

       alert(arr[0]);
       alert(arr[1]);
       alert(arr[2]);
   }
</script>
```

EDIT: Fixed after the author indicated PHP was also involved. Also note that JavaScript handles Associative Arrays weirdly.

Comment: i want to pass php variable in the function name and need to catch in the javascript